# Ordering the reduction potentials for Cr3+, Mn3+ and Fe3+?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

I have been asked to order, with explanation, the standard reduction potentials for the following:

1. $\ce{Cr^3+ + e- -> Cr^2+}$
2. $\ce{Mn^3+ + e- -> Mn^2+}$
3. $\ce{Fe^3+ + e- -> Fe^2+}$

(all ions in aqueous conditions)

I am really uncertain what factors to consider; I am even struggling to make this a general born-haber process. I know that $\mathrm{3^{rd}}$ ionization enthalpies will come into play, and that $\ce{Fe}$ will be expected to have the highest one. Will hydration enthalpies also be relevant? Will there be a ligand exchange component (with the solvent, water) that I have to consider also?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I'd like to say the *explanations* we propose here are merely our efforts trying to explain what we observed *experimentally* in the first place. Let's get some data:

$${\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline \ce{Cr^3+/ Cr^2+} & \ce{Mn^3+ / Mn^2+} & \ce{Fe^3+ / Fe^2+} \\ \hline \pu{-0.41 V} & \pu{+1.57 V} & \pu{+1.97 V} \\ \hline \end{array}}$$

And while we're at it, let's ponder on electronic configurations as well:

$${\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline \ce{Mn^2+} & \pu{[Ar] 3d5 4s0} \\ \hline \ce{Fe^3+} & \pu{[Ar] 3d5 4s0} \\ \hline \end{array}}$$

You were correct in thinking that $\ce{Fe^3+}$ will have the highest reduction potential due to the third ionization enthalpy coming into play, all we've got to do now is to *think* for manganese and chromium. Why don't we put it differently:

> Why is $\ce{Cr^2+}$ reducing and $\ce{Mn^3+}$ oxidizing when they both have the same $\pu{d4}$ configuration?

It's because if manganese acts as an oxidizer, it'll get converted into $\ce{Mn^2+}$, which is stable owing to the $\pu{d5}$ configuration. Chromium, on the other hand is *notorious* for showing the $+3$ oxidation state in its compounds. So, that's a win-win kind of situation we're dealing with.

---

The subtle role played by the solvent molecules when they're acting as ligands comes into limelight on asking yet another relevant question:

> Which is a stronger reducing agent: $\ce{Cr^2+}$ or $\ce{Fe^2+}$?

**Answer:** $\ce{Cr^2+}$. This is because of more CFSE stabilization of $\ce{Cr^3+}$ as compared to $\ce{Fe^3+}$ when water molecules behave as a ligand for our complex.

Comment: this has really helped with pointing me in the right direction-thank you so much!!!